# Find if numbers in an array are between two numbers and output number of values that are between

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying for the past few hours to find out how to find numbers in array that are between 2 numbers and I don't know where to go. What do I need to do? 18 and 20 are just placeholder numbers, feel free to use any numbers you want.

```
function start() {
    var array = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
    var lower = 18;
    var upper = 20;

    if (need help here) {
        alert('Yes');
    } else {
        alert('No');
    }

    document.getElementById('listOfvalues').innerHTML = ('There are ' + ___ + ' numbers that are between the two numbers);
    document.getElementById('numberExist').innerHTML = numberExist;
}
```

I know I haven't provided much, but I will go crazy if I try to do this myself

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: The final output will say the number of values between those 2 values. So in my example where I used 18 and 20, the final result should be '6'. This would vary with different values as constraints

Comment: please highlight, how do you get `6`.

Comment: Well, between 18 and 20, there is 18, 20, 18, 19, 18, 20. If, let's say the numbers were 20 and 30, 5 numbers fit the criteria, 23, 20, 21, 22, 20. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test, if the value is in the given range and count it.

```js
var array = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20],
    lower = 18,
    upper = 20,
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + (a >= lower && a <= upper);
    }, 0);

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var array = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20],
    lower = 18,
    upper = 20,
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => r + (a >= lower && a <= upper), 0);

console.log(result);
```

> How does [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) work in this case?
>
> You have an accumulator for the result, denoted as `r` and an actual value of the iteration, denoted as `a`. The returned result is the sum of the former count and the ckeck, if the value is in the given range.
>
> ```
>     r       a   return   comment
> ------  ------  ------  --------
>     0      18       1   in range
>     1      23       1
>     1      20       2   in range
>     2      17       2
>     2      21       2
>     2      18       3   in range
>     3      22       3
>     3      19       4   in range
>     4      18       5   in range
>     5      20       6   in range
>     6                   result
> ```

Some thoughts, all in ES6 style.

You could use a callback for `Array#reduce` with a closure over `lower` and `upper`, like

```js
var array = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20],
    getCountInRange = (lower, upper) => (r, a) => r + (a >= lower && a <= upper);

console.log(array.reduce(getCountInRange(18, 20), 0));
```

or you could use a function which takes the array, `lower` and `upper` and returns the count.

```js
var array = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20],
    getCountInRange = (array, lower, upper) => array.reduce((r, a) => r + (a >= lower && a <= upper), 0);

console.log(getCountInRange(array, 18, 20));
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. One question though to help my understanding of your code. How does the use of function(r, a) work? I am used to calling a function elsewhere within the code, not in the style you have presented. Also, how would I use your code in the way I am used to calling functions?

Answer (score 4):

```
var lower = 18;
var upper = 20;
var array = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
var between = array.filter(function(item) {
  return (item > lower && item < upper);
});
```

Comment: your complexity is currently O(2n) so you can double your performance if you check for item > lower && item <upper and filter just once...

Comment: Thanks @Jonasw, I have modified it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var listOfvalues=[];
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
       if (array[i]>18 && array[i]<20) {
           listOfvalues.push(array[i]);           
       } 
    }


    document.getElementById('listOfvalues').innerHTML = 'There are ' + listOfvalues.length + ' numbers that are between the two numbers';
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is the following:

```
// a changed (hopefully meaningful) name for the function,
// lower: Number, the lower-boundary,
// upper: Number, the upper-boundary,
// haystack: Array, the array of values:
function numbersBetween(lower, upper, haystack) {

  // if every value of the Array is, or can be coerced to,
  // a Number then we continue to work with that Array:
  if (haystack.every(value => Number(value))) {

    // Here we use Array.prototype.filter() to filter the
    // values of the Array according the function:
    return haystack.filter(

      // here we use an Arrow function, since we don't need
      // to use a 'this'; here we retain the current value ('n')
      // in the Array if that Number is greater than the
      // lower-boundary and lower than the upper-boundary:
      n => n > lower && n < upper
    );
  }

  // otherwise, if not every value is, or can be coerced,
  // to a Number we simply return an empty Array:
  return [];
}

// this caches the element with the id of 'output':
let list = document.getElementById('output'),

  // we create an <li> element:
  li = document.createElement('li'),

  // we create a document fragment:
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),

  // and an empty uninitialised variable:
  clone;

// we call the numbersBetween function, passing in the relevant
// boundaries and the Array:
numbersBetween(7, 20, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15])

// because the function returns an Array (either an empty Array or
// an Array with values), we can chain the function using
// Array.prototype.forEach():
.forEach(

  // here we use another Arrow function expression:
  num => {

    // clone the created <li> element and assign it
    // the 'clone' variable:
    clone = li.cloneNode();

    // set the clone's textContent to be equal to
    // the current Array-element of the Array over
    // which we're iterating:
    clone.textContent = num;

    // and append that cloned-element to the
    // document.fragment:
    fragment.appendChild(clone);
  });

// this could be used in the last iteration of the
// Array.prototype.forEach() method, but because it
// generates no errors (an empty document fragment
// can be appended to an element without consequence),
// we perform this step here, appending the document
// fragment to the cached 'list' element which appends
// the nodes contained within the document fragment to
// the specified parent-node (list):
list.appendChild(fragment);
```

```js
function numbersBetween(lower, upper, haystack) {
  if (haystack.every(value => Number(value))) {

    return haystack.filter(
      n => n > lower && n < upper
    );
  }
  return [];
}

let list = document.getElementById('output'),
  li = document.createElement('li'),
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  clone;

numbersBetween(7, 20, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15]).forEach(
  num => {
    clone = li.cloneNode();
    clone.textContent = num;
    fragment.appendChild(clone);
  });
list.appendChild(fragment);
```

```css
#output::before {
  content: 'The following numbers were found:';
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#output:empty::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2d2q2coL/).

Comment: return haystack.reduce((a,n)=>(a?((n>lower&&n<upper)?a.push(n):false):a),[]) || []; bit shorter/faster than your filter & every

Comment: It's also a little more difficult to read; and I'll sacrifice speed for readability (almost) every time. I may be only a hobbyist but should anyone use my answers in their production code I'd like to be somewhat sure they aren't in danger from their own colleagues knowing where they live... :)

Comment: touché sir ;). I wrote it that unreadable because its in the comment section, it could be expanded easily to improve readability...

Answer (score 0):

Providing a filtered solution to Wei's answer

```
var array = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
var lower = 18;
var upper = 20;

var result = array.filter(function(item) {
  return item >= lower && item <= upper;
});

document.getElementById('listOfvalues').innerHTML = ('There are ' + result.length + ' numbers that are between the two numbers);
```

In short, use the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return results according to your low and high boundaries. Print the length of the returned array of values.

For the if/else statement you can do by yourself.

Edit: Added link to filter

Comment: This works. Thank you. One question though to help my understanding of your code. How does the use of function(item) work? I am used to calling a function elsewhere within the code, not in the style you have presented.

Comment: while this works, i do no suggest such solution, because you need two iterations and you create two arrays with items, whereas you need only the count of it.

Comment: Using function(item) means that item takes the place of each element in the array. In your case in the first time item is 18, following by 23, 20, and so on. If the answer fulfils your question, accept would be appreciated.